# Mean stack installation on ubuntu 12.10 fails

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mean-stack

I'm trying to install mean stack https://github.com/linnovate/mean on ubuntu 12.10 but getting the following error when running npm install:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd mean@0.1.0 bower install (wd=/var/www/mean)
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/mean/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/bower-config requires mout@'~0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/mean/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/mean/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent requires methods@'0.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/mean/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/methods,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.0
```

Been searching around but can't seem to find a solution...

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same issue on MacOS X 10.9.

Managed to fix it by updating Node and NPM to the latest version (v0.10.22) then following the details in the troubleshooting section on the project's GitHub page - https://github.com/linnovate/mean#troubleshooting.

Hope that helps.